# Unable to connect Database inside a subroutine perl

Tags: perl, database-connection

I am facing a problem while creating a my `SQL` database connection  inside a `subroutine`. below code is saved on server with file name as "ALabel"

```
package ALabel;
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '/var/www/cgi-bin/ssiweb824/Navik';



sub ALabelPipe
{

    my $sth;
    my $sql;
    my @idarr=@_;
my $id=@idarr[0];
my $databasename=@idarr[1];
my $code=@idarr[2];

    my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database=$databasename','username','password');        

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 where ID='".$id."'"."and Pcode='".$code."'";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute;
    $dbh->disconnect;
    my @abc = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    return $abc[2];


}
```

And, below is how I am accessing the ALabel file and accessing this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '/var/www/cgi-bin/ssiweb824/Navik';
use ALabel;
my $qid1="QTG"
$studyname="databasename"
my $abc=ALabel::ALabelPipe('$qid1',$studyname,1);
return $abc;
```

This code works fine when I write `$dbh` outside Alabel pipe subroutine, but since I need to make my database name dynamic and need to pass it as a parameter I need to call it inside ALabelpipe function. can someone please help me?

Comment: Please please please use placeholders.

Comment: The first things I notice is you are missing statement-ending semi-colons in the "accessing" script, and trying to interpolate `$qid1` within single-quotes which won't work. Please put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in the script, remove the single-quotes around the variable, and correct the statements which have no `;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `'$qid1'` won't interpolate/evaluate to `QTG`. Use plain `$qid1` (just the variable name, no quotes at all) in the function call.

Evidence:

```
perl -e "$qid1='QTG'; print '$qid1';"
$qid1

perl -e "$qid1='QTG'; print $qid1;"
QTG
```

Additional blunders found:

1. Missing `;` # (c) stevieb
2. Wrong sigil `@` when accessing array elements: `my $id=@idarr[0];` should be `my $id = $idarr[0];`.

Comment: Note the missing `;` at the end of some of the statements in the same code snip...